# Problem with CSS3Pie alpha inheritance in IE8

Tags: css, cross-browser, css3pie

I have some markup kind of like this

```
<div class="background">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab">tab</li>
    <li class="tab">tab</li>
    <li class="tab">tab</li>
    <li class="tab">tab</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using css3pie I have a the background with an rgba transparency but the alpha from the background is cascading down to the tabs in ie8 only.

Does anyone know how I can stop that inheritance or if there is some configuration in css3pie that I need to do to stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position needed to be set to `position: relative` on the tabs